# Call rest void method in controller using Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, vaadin

i'm using Spring Boot for making Rest Controllers.

my controller is :

```
@RestController
public class VersionRestController {

    @Autowired
    VersionService versionService;
    
    @GetMapping(value = "/csv", produces = "text/csv")
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
    public void exportCsv(HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

        String fileName = "allVersions.csv";

        response.setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"");

        StatefulBeanToCsv<Version> writer = new StatefulBeanToCsvBuilder<Version>(response.getWriter())
                .withQuotechar(CSVWriter.NO_QUOTE_CHARACTER).withSeparator(CSVWriter.DEFAULT_SEPARATOR)
                .withOrderedResults(true).build();

        writer.write(versionService.findAll());
    }
    
}
```

im calling it like this

```
    public void exportVersionAsCsv(){
        

        final String uri = "http://localhost:8070/csv";
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

        ResponseEntity<Version> response = restTemplate.getForEntity(uri, Version.class);
        
    }
```

when i call the rest method direct in the browser it works fine, but when i call `exportVersionAsCsv()` in vaadin on click button it gives me  `org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$NotAcceptable: 406 Not Acceptable`

why is this happening ? any suggestion ?
thank you

Comment: Ofcourse it won't work, you are using `getForEntity` but are sending an attachment (multi-part) and not json.

Comment: what to do then ?

Comment: You are producing a CSV which is something you cannot marshal to a response. You can use the `execute` method and obtain the CSV with a `ResponseExtractor`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this set setAccept to Media type to that is being produced by url you are consuming.

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>("body", headers);
restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, entity, String.class);
```